# Textbox always filled blue and cursor not keeping on left in IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Textbox is always filled up with blue color only in IE, also the cursor is not keeping on left. This issue is only on IE not on chrome or firefox. I am using this for all browsers.

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="input" id="I_6_53" maxlength="10" style="width: 98px; text-transform: uppercase;   position: absolute; left: 120px; top: 95px;" name="InputField0" type="text">
```

Comment: Do you have other css that might be confounding this?  Perhaps in an external stylesheet?

Comment: No I do not have any other css involved